# How are multiplication maps of spectra defined?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

In [lecture 22](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/252xnotes/Lecture22.pdf) of [Lurie's notes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chromatic+Homotopy+Theory) on chromatic homotopy theory there is the following cryptic definition.

> For each integer $k$, let $M(k)$ denote the cofiber of the map $Σ^{2k} \mathrm{MU}(p) \to \mathrm{MU}(p)$ given by multiplication
> by $t_k$.

Here, $\mathrm{MU}(p)$ is mod-$p$ complex bordism, which I presume means the localization of $\mathrm{MU}$ at $\mathrm{H}\mathbb{F}_p$, and $t_k$ is a generator of $\pi_{2k}(\mathrm{MU}(p))$.

> **Question.** What does this mean?

Some thoughts: I can interpret $\Sigma^{2k} \mathrm{MU}(p)$ as $\Sigma^{\infty}S^{2k} \wedge \mathrm{MU}(p)$, so we can consider a map $\Sigma^{\infty} S^{2k} \wedge \mathrm{MU}(p) \to \mathrm{MU}(p) \wedge \mathrm{MU}(p)$ defined by, say, $t_k \wedge \operatorname{Id}$, followed by some kind of multiplication map on $\operatorname{MU}(p)$. I believe $\operatorname{MU}$ is a ring spectrum, which I think implies that $\mathrm{MU}$ admits a multiplication map of some sort. Maybe that's what's being implied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectrum $MU$ is a *ring spectrum*. This means that it comes a equiped with a 'product' map $\mu:MU\wedge MU\rightarrow MU$ as well as a unit $\eta:S\rightarrow MU$, which together make all the obvious diagrams (homotopy) commute. Then if $x\in\pi_rMU$, multiplication by $x$ is the composite

$$\hat x:S^r\wedge MU\xrightarrow{x\wedge 1}MU\wedge MU\xrightarrow{\mu}MU.$$

It is standard to drop the hat and denote the induced map by the same symbol as the element $x\in\pi_rMU$. Thus $t_k\in\pi_{2k}MU$ is a generator and the map you are interested in is what I have called $\hat{t}^k$ in the previous notation.

In response to your second question, why are you learning homotopy theory? If it is beacuse you want to become a homotopy theorist, then I'm afraid you will need to put up with the jargon, since this is the language in which we have come to communicate. One point of advice I would offer is to not start with Lurie's notes if this is your first introduction to the subject. They are beautifully written, but as you have found with your question, are not for the beginner. Moreover they are the transcripts of a set of lectures, rather than a dedicated text, and as it always is, there is more knowledge imparted during the actual lecture than is collected on paper afterwards. If you are leaning homotopy theory as a complement to some other subject, then you may do well to try out a text written by someone with a closer background to yours.

Comment: p.s. the 'obvious' diagrams correspond to the associativity $\mu(1\wedge\mu)\simeq \mu(\mu\wedge1):MU\wedge MU\wedge MU\rightarrow MU$ and unit $\mu(1\wedge\eta)\simeq \mu(\eta\wedge 1)\simeq id_{MU}:S\wedge MU\cong MU\wedge S\cong MU\rightarrow MU$.

Comment: Thanks, Tyrone. Two questions: Does the ring structure on $MU$ induce a ring structure on $MU_{(p)}$ (and more generally, are Bousfield localizations of ring spectra again ring spectra)? Second, I'm reading Lurie's notes because I don't know an alternative. I'm hoping to learn more about Morava E-theory and K-theory but all sources use very terse and complicated language which I, as a beginner, just don't get. Is there a source you'd recommend?

Comment: I believe that $MU_{(p)}$ does inherit a ring structure. In fact Bousfield discusses this himself in his paper "The Localization of Spectra with Respect to Homology". As i understand it, $p$-localisation is a so-called 'smashing' localisation, so $MU_{p}\simeq MU\wedge S_{(p)}$, where $S_{(p)}$ is the $p$-local sphere, so things work out fairly easily. (Although I'd recommend checking these statements)

Comment: I do think Lurie's notes are very good, but limited in the sense I wrote above. I'm not sure I can make a good recommendation in general for a set of notes. I know Morava K-theory is discussed in Ravenel's classics
"Complex Cobordism and Stable Homotopy Groups of Spheres" and "Nilpotence and Periodicity in Stable Homotopy Theory". The presentation there is very low-tech compared to Lurie's, however.

Comment: For some background you could read Würgler's, "Morava K-Theories: A Survey" and its references. This paper is now quite old, and you are probably already above most of it, but you might be interested to see the material presented in a more standard way. Alternately, Mike Hopkins is the deserved golden boy of modern stable homotopy theory, and I believe he together with Ravenel and others has written a fair bit about chromatic homotopy theory, elliptic cohomology, etc...

Comment: You're a saint, Tyrone. I followed your suggestion that smashing localizations send ring spectra to ring spectra, and I'm convinced it works out (though I'm stuck proving a diagram that looks seriously commutative really is commutative). I'm going to look up the references you mentioned and see if it helps me out. Thanks again.

Comment: @guest Abstractly, a smashing localization is a Bousfield localization such that the localization functor is *monoidal*, that is, preserves smash products up to a natural morphism. The statement "any monoidal functor between monoidal categories preserves monoids" specializes to "any smashing localization preserves ring spectra", and you might find it easier to write down a proof of the former. At least that gives some other words to look up.